# Exchange Server Moderated-Transport

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server

I have created a rule in Exchange Admin Server (EAC) that forwards a specific message for approval, to the admin.

The problem is when the message match the rule, it needs to go to an offline server which had a Discovery Database (I don't know if because it has this Discovey Database). I can see it in the "Queue Viewer" blocked trying to connect to the ip of this offline server..
But when I change the rule to onlu forward the message (without approval) to the admin, it works.

Comment: I just understand that the "arbritration" mailbox is in the database of the offline server.. that is why it want to connect to it.. the offline server is lost so is its database.. I don't know what to do, please help.

Comment: Is this a programming question? StackOverflow is for programming questions only. Sounds more like this belongs to https://ServerFault.com

Comment: yes I think it is programming question as I should use Powershell and commadlines in order to resolve the problem? Thank you for helping.

Comment: It's not a programming question if you're just changing settings etc with powershell. If you're actually coding something for your logic, then it's a programming question -- but your question does not mention that at all.